# array single cell value until next cell with value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, vlookup, array-formulas, nested-if

How can I take the value from the above cell, and get an array of it until it meets a non-empty cell.
All must happen in the same column

Example:

| Column A |
| --- |
| INPUT (any value) |
| copy of A1 |
| copy of A1 |
| copy of A1 (the array stops here, because next cell isn't empty) |
| ANOTHER VALUE |

The array should stop without the "overwrite data" error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible, but you cant jump over existing values so you need a formula in A2, A6, etc...

another solution would be: **https://stackoverflow.com/a/69140434/5632629**